# Passing data between Projects by Servlet about RemoteUser

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

i'm getting some problems with the method getRemoteUser() implementation on 2 projects, let's explain:

I've a "Principal" project where i'm able to retrieve the remote User in a JSP simply calling

```
${pageContext.request.remoteUser}
```

The problem come when i try to call the same remoteUser from another project who i reach with a redirect from the first one, can anyone explain me how the remote user is set in websphere and how i can check if this is done even for the second project? Thank you.

Comment: What I got: you have two servlets, they need authentication to access them. Authentication for the first servlet is not "transferred" to the second.
 - Did I understand your problem correct?
 - Are both servlets deployed into different contexts?
 - How is the authentication for the "Principal" project configured?

Comment: What errors do you face?Is the method implementation available in second project too?Is @cyberbrain understanding correct?